Qu'entend Roland Barthes par "la différence engage tout Kafka"?
Dans son article de 1960 intitulé "La réponse de Kafka", Roland Barthes après avoir fait référence à l'avis de Marthe Robert et l'ayant résumé comme "le récit de Kafka n'est pas tissé de symboles [...] mais qu'il est le fruit d'une technique toute différente, celle de l'allusion", continue par "La différence engage tout Kafka".
Est-il correct d’interpréter cette phrase comme "on peut trouver trace/instances de cette différence dans toute l’œuvre de Kafka"?  Ou bien y a-t-il d'autres significations portées par le verbe engager dans ce contexte?
Merci d'avance pour tout éclaircissement.

Oui on peut. La différence est celle des techniques, symbolique/allusive: elle {investit | imprègne | contamine | percole dans | etc.} toute l'oeuvre de Kafka.

Toute réflexion faite: oui cette interprétation est correcte. j'en propose une autre, compatible et plus radicale: Toute l'oeuvre de Kafka change d'aspect à la lumière de cette différence. Cette interprétation sous-entend que  les critiques s'engagent dans des approches différentes de son oeuvre selon qu'ils acceptent ou ignorent l'observation de M. Robert.

@FrançoisJurain Vous semblez adhérer à/proposer deux interprétations dont l'une serait correcte ; ne voulez-vous pas plutôt parler de deux interprétations qui seraient toutes deux plausibles ?

@LPH je crois correctes les deux interprétations: celle de l'OP et la mienne. Je souligne de plus qu'elles ne s'excluent pas l'une l'autre. Tertio, j'essaie de reformuler la phrase de Barthes sans lui faire dire que les analyses antérieures à celle de M. Robert seraient caduques.

@FrançoisJurain Par « correcte » je sous-entend bien sûr « interprétation voulue par Barthes ». En ce sens les deux ne peuvent pas être correctes.

@FrançoisJurain J'ai peine à croire que Barthes ait souhaité que sa formulation prête à l'ambigüité. // Quelle serait la définition de « engager » du TLFi que vous retiendriez pour expliquer cette phrase ?

Il me semble que "Cette différence" ne serait pas la même chose que "La différence".

@Lambie Par "cette différence" j'entendais "la différence [à laquelle fait référence la phrase précédente]", à savoir celle de la technique de l'allusion avec celle des symboles.

@AramGharib C'est à dire « l'allusion ».

Les VTC (il en reste 1 à l'instant où j'écris) me laissent perplexe. Je ne crois pas que l'OP ait sollicité nos opinions sur l'exégèse de Kafka ou la critique barthienne: simplement, une phrase qu'il a lue lui pose problème. Ce que j'en comprends:
Problème. Quelle est l'acception d'"engager" dans la phrase: La différence engage tout Kafka ?
Mille mercis @LPH pour cette suggestion d'en revenir aux dictionnaires.
Or donc, je lis dans fr.wkt:
https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/engager

(Sens 7: ) Faire entrer une chose dans une autre où elle est prise.

Donc: "La différence fait entrer tout[e l'œuvre de] Kafka dans une chose où elle est prise."
Quelle est la chose en question? L'un de deux appareillages critiques de l'écriture kafkaïesque, échafaudés différemment: pour le premier, sur le récit tissé de symboles, pour le second, sur la technique de l'allusion.
Cette glose est compatible avec l'interprétation proposée par l'OP, qui est toutefois beaucoup moins pointue: on peut trouver trace/instances de cette différence dans toute l’œuvre de Kafka.
Le TLFi reconnaît un emploi absolu d'"engager" qui dispense l'auteur de gloser: déf. II.B.3.

Ils veulent bien renoncer aux grandeurs qui engagent l'homme. (Péguy)


Une pareille phrase est véritablement bourgeoise. Elle engage et n'engage point. (Nizan).

Ajouté après commentaires.
À la définition proposée en commentaire par l'OP: la III.A.1.b). du TLFi, je préfère la III.B.1.c) qui me paraît mieux adaptée:

Mettre en jeu, faire intervenir, comme élément nécessaire. Synon.
demander, exiger.

Le TLFi donne un exemple de cette acception:

Je ne sais pas d'art qui puisse engager plus d'intelligence que le dessin (Valéry).

Retirons les fioritures et revenons à Barthes:

"L'art du dessin est de ceux qui engagent l'intelligence."
"La différence [relevée par Marthe Robert] est de celles qui engagent tout[e l'œuvre de] Kafka."

Nous voilà rendus:

"L'art du dessin engage l'intelligence."
"La différence engage tout Kafka."


Cette réponse dit "cette différence dans toute l’œuvre de Kafka" alors que le texte dit: La différence engage etc.. Faut pas oublier, à mon avis, la différence chez Derrida et compagnie. Mais je ne sais pas comment.

Il y a aussi la définition (https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/Engager) III.A.1.b: "Faire entrer, faire pénétrer quelqu'un ou quelque chose dans un espace généralement resserré pour qu'il en sorte, malgré les obstacles ou les difficultés qui pourraient le retenir ou le vaincre.", dont on pourrait imaginer qu'un Barthes puisse se dispenser de désambiguïser le complément.

La définition 7  dit « faire entrer une chose dans une autre » (« engagée dans un manche, engage dans le fendoir, engage dans l'ouverture » ; c'est « III. A.1. » du TLFi : (les prep. « à » et « entre » aussi) « engagé à sa ceinture, engagé entre les mâchoires, engageait dans son établi, engageait le fer « y » (c'est à dire dans le chêne), engageait dans l'étrier »); de plus que rien de figuré ne soit pris en compte dans cette définition, le sens est  « coincer » ; la différence coincerait l'œuvre de Kafka dans quelque chose (qui n'est même pas mentionné) ? Non-sens le plus complet. (1/2)

Pour que « II.B.3. » convienne, nécessaire que  sujet soit  inanimé abstrait, ce qui conviendrait, mais il doit aussi être  « du type : honneur, parole, serment, signature »; de plus, objet doit être une personne ;  pas le cas puisque vous avez convenu  « Kafka » signifiait « œuvre Kafka ». Un synonyme serait « obliger », et donc, la différence obligerait l'œuvre de Kafka, ce qui n'a encore une fois, pas le moindre sens. Si vous suivez les directives des dictionnaire vous êtes forcé de conclure que vos déductions ne cadrent pas du tout. (2/2)

@AramGharib Pour « III. A » il faut que le sujet soit une personne ; qu'il s'agisse de « allusion » ou de « différence » le sujet n'est pas une personne.

@LPH Faux: "Faire entrer, faire pénétrer quelqu'un ou quelque chose dans un espace..." Il s'agit bien de "la différence"... Relisez votre citation ci-dessous.

@AramGharib Essayez de mettre les parties les unes en dessous des autres sur une feuille de papier. « La différence engage tout Kafka » (La différence fait pénétrer qqch (dans une chose)…» : La partie « dans une chose » manque ; « la différence » est le sujet ; « qqch », c'est « Kafka », le cod.

Vu l'an dernier dans la presse française aussi le diagnostic vital n'est pas engagé.

L'interprétation « on peut trouver trace/instances de cette différence dans toute l'œuvre de Kafka » peut sourire au lecteur  qui se borne au contexte étroit de la phrase qui le suggère, mais il y a tout d'abord, dans le but de vérifier cette interprétation,  l'écueil de l'absence  au TLfi  d'une définition qu'on puisse réconcilier avec cette idée (le sujet doit être un inanimé abstrait, voir les définitions).  Seulement « B.- 1.  c) »   (1. [L'obj. désigne une pers. ou un attribut d'une pers.],  [Le suj. désigne un inanimé abstr.]) peut convenir selon ce dictionnaire. Autrement dit, « Kafka » n'aurait pas pour sens « l'œuvre de Kafka » mais « l'auteur, Kafka ». Donc la différence ferait intervenir la personne de Kafka « toute entière », c'est à dire dans ses moindres actes.
Vient ensuite une énigmatique constatation que la prolongation de la lecture apporte. Le texte initial et l'addition dont il est question sont reproduits ci-dessous. (parties en caractères gras et italique dues à user LPH)

Mais dire que la Littérature n'est qu'interrogation au monde n'a de poids que si l'on propose une véritable technique de l'interrogation, puisque cette interrogation doit durer à travers un récit d'apparence assertive. Marthe Robert montre très bien que le récit de Kafka n'est pas tissé de symboles, comme on l'a dit cent fois, mais qu'il est le fruit d'une technique toute différente, celle de l'allusion. La différence engage tout Kafka. Le symbole (la croix du christianisme, par exemple) est un signe sûr, il affirme une analogie (partielle) entre une forme et une idée, il implique une certitude. Si les figures et les événements du récit kafkaïen étaient symboliques, ils renverraient à une philosophie positive (même désespérée), à un Homme universel : on ne peut diverger sur le sens d'un symbole, faute de quoi le symbole est manqué. Or le récit de Kafka autorise mille clefs également plausibles, c'est-à-dire qu'il n'en valide aucune. Tout autre est l'allusion. Elle renvoie l'événement romanesque à autre chose que lui même, mais à quoi ? L'allusion est une force défective, elle défait l'analogie sitôt qu'elle l'a posée. K. est arrêté sur l'ordre d'un Tribunal : voilà une image familière de la Justice. Mais nous apprenons que ce Tribunal ne conçoit pas du tout les délits comme notre Justice : la ressemblance est déçue, sans cependant s'effacer. En somme, comme l'explique bien Marthe Robert, tout procède d'une sorte de contraction sémantique : K. se sent arrêté, et tout se passe comme si K. était réellement arrêté (Le Procès) ; le père de Kafka le traite de parasite, et tout se passe comme si Kafka était métamorphosé en parasite (La Métamorphose). Kafka fonde son œuvre en en supprimant systématiquement les « comme si » : mais c'est l'événement intérieur qui devient le terme obscur de l'allusion. On le voit, l'allusion, qui est une pure technique de signification, engage en fait le monde entier, puisqu'elle exprime le rapport d'un homme singulier et d'un langage commun : un système (fantôme abhorré de tous les antiintellectualismes) produit l'une des littératures les plus brûlantes que nous ayons connues. Par exemple (rappelle Marthe Robert), on dit couramment : comme un chien, une vie de chien, chien de Juif ; il suffit de faire du terme métaphorique l'objet plein du récit, renvoyant la subjectivité dans le domaine allusif, pour que l'homme insulté soit vraiment un chien : l'homme traité comme un chien est un chien. La technique de Kafka implique donc d'abord un accord au monde, une soumission au langage courant, mais aussitôt après, une réserve, un doute, un effroi devant la lettre des signes proposés par le monde. Marthe Robert dit excellemment que les rapports de Kafka et du monde sont réglés par un perpétuel : oui, mais...

On est amené à l'idée que si le récit était symbolique, on aurait affaire à un Homme universel ; puis on nous dit que « l'allusion »—que nous reconnaissons, indépendamment de ce qu'on nous dit, comme rien d'autre que cette différence que  Barthes caractérise en cela qu'elle « engage tout Kafka »—, « engage » maintenant le « monde entier », ce qui n'est encore une fois qu'une personne, si une personne « collective », même si la plus générale et insaisissable. De plus, l'analogie  se retrouve dans cette nouvelle phrase  à un niveau de perfection saisissant : l'« allusion » qui n'est que la « différence » sous une autre guise,  encore une fois  engage quelque chose dans son entièreté. Finalement, l'opposition entre l'« Homme universel » associé au symbolisme incompatible avec la pensée de Kafka, et  un homme singulier, qui est évidemment Kafka, un représentant de ce « monde dans son entièreté », consolide plus certainement l'interprétation de « Kafka » en tant qu'auteur et non de « Kafka » en tant qu'« œuvre de Kafka ».
Tout porte à croire que l'interprétation correcte serait « l'allusion fait intervenir la personne de Kafka dans ses moindres actes », ou en d'autres mots « tout l'art littéraire  de Kafka sert l'allusion ».
Additions dues au commentaires
(user Aram Gharib "Tout Kafka", en soi, ne désigne pas forcément la personne: c'est le contexte qui désambiguïse (e.g. "j'ai lu tout Kafka"). D'ailleurs à quoi se réfèrerait "tout"? Franz Kafka évitait-il le symbolisme dans sa façon de s'habiller et préférait l'allusion dans son choix d'itinéraire pour aller au bureau? Il semble évident que la différence entre symbolisme et allusion n'est applicable qu'à son activité litéraire... Donc "tout Kafka" signifierait, grosso modo (et d'ailleurs pas si grosso que ça!), "toute l'oeuvre litéraire de Kafka".)
Je pense que « tout Kafka » sous-entend « Kafka dans son activité littéraire » ; d'ailleurs, que dire ensuite de « l'allusion … engage … le monde entier »? Le « monde » dans son interaction ne serait-il appréhensible que par le processus de l'allusion ? Non je ne crois pas ça, il doit s'agir du monde que Kafka met en scène dans sa littérature, et il est engagé par l'allusion par l'intermédiaire de la plume de Kafka, lequel ne veut voir que par l'allusion. Il y a dans ces deux parties, me semble-t-il un parallèle extraordinaire qui ne peut pas être ignoré. Pourquoi cette répétition insistante de formes analogiques qui risquerait beaucoup de porter le lecteur à la méprise ? Serait-ce une coïncidence fortuite ? Je ne le crois pas non plus ; l'auteur aurait probablement eu le tact d'éviter cette ambigüité.


Une interprétation ne m'a jamais souri. 2. Si tu tiens toujours à te nommer "user LPH", met au moins user en italiques. 3. Sous une autre guise : Est-il vraiment nécessaire d'utiliser une expression aussi archaïque ?


@jlliagre sourire (TLFi) : Convenir, être agréable, plaire à. // Au diable ceux qui sont si pressés d'enterrer la langue acquise : 2024 : https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Le_capital_que_je_ne_suis_pas/Gwv0EAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22sous+une+autre+guise%22&pg=PT71&printsec=frontcover // Pas d'italique, du meta-language FSE .

-1 alors, puisque tu ne tiens pas compte des remarques. Quand il n'y a qu'un seul locuteur, difficile de parler de meta-langage.

@jlliagre Oh oui,  -1,  après être allé au cœur du problème ! Bonne lecture !

"Tout Kafka", en soi, ne désigne pas forcément la personne: c'est le contexte qui désambiguïse (e.g. "j'ai lu tout Kafka"). D'ailleurs à quoi se réfèrerait "tout"? Franz Kafka évitait-il le symbolisme dans sa façon de s'habiller et préférait l'allusion dans son choix d'itinéraire pour aller au bureau? Il semble évident que la différence entre symbolisme et allusion n'est applicable qu'à son activité litéraire... Donc "tout Kafka" signifierait, grosso modo (et d'ailleurs pas si grosso que ça!), "toute l'oeuvre litéraire de Kafka".

@AramGharib Réponse à votre commentaire dans mon post.
